# The right way to set event handlers in class method

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've met this problem already a couple of times. And I don't really have somebody experienced to help me. So the main question is how to properly set click handlers via jquery inside class method, while having access to object's context.
Notice, that my code is working, but I feel like the way its done is ugly, so Im just looking for expanding my knowledge to do this `right` way.

So I have simple class, which while initializing is setting click handler, to get some html data from server via `$.ajax()`, then putting it at some `div` and setting up a new handler on a click inside that data received and put in DOM. Here is a piece of code that I've came to:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(params) {
        this.data = params.data;
        this.setInitHandlers();
    }

    setInitHandlers() {
        $(".link").click(function(e){
            $.ajax({
                url: this.data.url,
                dataType: "html",
                data: {data: this.data},
                success: function(data) {
                    $("div").append(data);
                    $("div .button-inside-div").click(function(e){
                        /*some actions*/
                    }.bind(this));
                }.bind(this)
            });
        }.bind(this));
    }
}
```

So this is just an example of what I have troubles with. But having answer on this question I'll be able to have better understanding on how can I code better in general. I don't like this infinite binding of context. So I just want an advice from some bigbrains here, is this hurting your eyes, and how it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid binding `this` so many times, use arrow functions, with the first one being the normal function.

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(params) {
        this.data = params.data;
        this.setInitHandlers = this.setInitHandlers.bind(this);
        // Now call setInitHandlers from anywhere
    }

    setInitHandlers() {
        $(".link").click( e => {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.data.url, // this refers to class object
                dataType: "html",
                data: {data: this.data}, // this refers to the class object
                success: data => {
                    $("div").append(data);
                    $("div .button-inside-div").click( e => {
                        /*some actions*/
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```